# A module failed and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called

Tags: javascript, react-native

New to react-native, and I got this error:

```
    * A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes
```

here is my index.js:

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import { name as appName } from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

and I have put the codes below in my app.json,

```
{
  "name": "EatNGo",
  "displayName": "EatNGo"
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure you are running the project in the correct directory. then clear cache data for android and iOS. (wipe data). if you are using yarn or npm, try cleaning the cache. hope it works.

Comment: I have tried this `npm cache clean --force`, and it worked